# Define object bool by comparing its properties

Tags: c#

Would it somehow be possible to define the `UserWin` property directly in the model by comparing `ClientCoinSide` and `ServerCoinSide`?

```cs
namespace Gambling.Core.Models.BetResult
{
    public class Coinflip
    {
        public CoinSide ClientCoinSide { get; set; }
        public CoinSide ServerCoinSide { get; set; }
        public bool ClientWin { get; }
    }

    public enum CoinSide
    {
        Heads,
        Tails
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClientWin` property would have to only define a `get` function, which would calculate whether the user wins. Assuming that the logic here would be that the client's coin side would have to be equal to that of the server's, this is how you have to do it:

```cs
        public CoinSide ClientCoinSide { get; set; }
        public CoinSide ServerCoinSide { get; set; }
        public bool ClientWin
        {
            get
            {
                return ClientCoinSide == ServerCoinSide;
            }
        }
```

which can be further simplified to:

```cs
        public CoinSide ClientCoinSide { get; set; }
        public CoinSide ServerCoinSide { get; set; }
        public bool ClientWin => ClientCoinSide == ServerCoinSide;
```

Comment: Happy to learn something new, thank you!
P.-S.: Topic probably is a duplicate but I didn't knew what to search for and couldn't find, sorry.